# Function to get Pattern R123456 ,Total length=7,start with character and only have digits from 2nd to 7th place

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

REGEX is not available in SQL and Cannot have access to Visual Studio .

There is one output here shorturl.at/ovACN but its for MYSQL.

What I need is for SQL.

REGEX is not working with SQL.

When we are trying to do

```
REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

in SQL its giving non boolean expression error.

How can I get only these patterns (R123456,m123456,y729472) and not like these (R12AS56,mS23456,y7294D2)

Like operator is not working and not getting what exactly I should use to get this output (R123456,m123456,y729472)

MYSQL

```
where COlumn name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';
```

ORACLE:

```
where REGEXP (COlumn nane,'^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

Output  = R123456,m123456,y729472

Actual error msg with REGEXP function

Comment: SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO  I am using .But when i am keeping regexp in my function its giving Non Boolean Expression Error.How to solve this issue

Comment: Select * from table where Column name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]';

Error(s), warning(s):

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'REGEXP'.

Comment: `LIKE 'R[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'` [RTFM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-by-using-like)

Comment: Cannot give hard coded value like 'R%' or 'W%' .It can be anything from[a-zA-Z] and then 6 digits[0-9][0-9]...  @Luuk

Comment: @Julian I am not having access to VS for making some procedures as seeing that link which you have shared....Isnt any simple operator available for getting this pattern

Comment: No Output using Like operator http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b38e/19
Tried with different combos .not working .
Please anyone can help ..its urgent issue

Comment: What database are you using? In your sqlfiddle you have chosen `MySQL`.... ??

Comment: SQL db...i am not getting how can I crack that pattern.its Mysql preselected there @Luuk. Can you or anyone help with exact function to get desired output

Comment: SQL is tooo broad. There are different implementation, from different suppliers. Like MSSQL (or Microsoft SQL), ORACLE, MySQL, MariaDB, SQLite, PostgreSQL. So again, which database are you using?

Comment: SQL server management studio 2008/MSSQL 2014...BOTH

Comment: If you are using MS-SQL, than this works `SELECT name FROM cricket WHERE name LIKE '[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`. It will find all values starting with a letter, and followed by 6 digits.

Comment: What abt sql server management system(SSMS 2008)

Comment: Check [link](https://rextester.com/EILT14245). You will get your answer.

Comment: @JIKEN the code is really high level for me ...not getting .value/rdata is there...just want to ask if Like Operator and then that condition where name like '[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'; will work for SQL ... for desired output

Comment: Yes it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this code in MySQL:

```
where name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

The equivalent in Oracle is:

```
where regexp_like(name, '^[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

And in SQL Server is:

```
where name like '[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Comment: about MSSQL variant: The 'a-z' part can be left off, if using the default(?) collating sequence, which is case insensitive.  Also when looking for 1 letter followed by 6 digits, the last '%' should be left off.

Comment: So for sql(ssms) like operator will work anf it will give the expected output of 1 letter and 6 digits therr after